# R list within a dataframe calculation

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe df:

```
     tile_type_index
71                17
81                 8
71.1              17
81.1               8
71.2              17
71.3              17
                                               material_balance
71   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
81   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
71.1 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
81.1 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
71.2 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
71.3 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
     material_spend
71        0.3333333
81        0.3333333
71.1      0.3333333
81.1      0.3333333
71.2      0.3333333
71.3      0.3333333

df<-structure(list(tile_type_index = c(17L, 8L, 17L, 8L, 17L, 17L
), material_balance = list(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), material_spend = c(0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333)), row.names = c("71", "81", "71.1", "81.1", 
"71.2", "71.3"), class = "data.frame"
```

For each row of df, I want to add material_spend to the element of material_balance that has the index given tile_type_index. So I want to do something like material_balance[tile_type_index]<-material_spend but I'm not sure how to do this.

The result should look like the following:

```
     tile_type_index
71                17
81                 8
71.1              17
81.1               8
71.2              17
71.3              17
                                               material_balance
71   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.33, 0, 0, 0
81   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
71.1 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.33, 0, 0, 0
81.1 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
71.2 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.33, 0, 0, 0
71.3 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.33, 0, 0, 0
     material_spend
71        0.3333333
81        0.3333333
71.1      0.3333333
81.1      0.3333333
71.2      0.3333333
71.3      0.3333333
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr` for this. Normally `dplyr` assumes that you are operating on entire columns at once, but this is a special row-wise operation so we use the `rowwise()` verb. Then we can also use the `replace` function to replace part of a vector and return the updated value. Because you have a list column, we need to wrap the result in a list so the resulting value has a length of 1. So this should work

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(material_balance = list(replace(material_balance, tile_type_index, material_spend)))
```

Comment: or `replace` instead of `\`[<-\``

Comment: @rawr. Good point. I'll update with that instead

Comment: Thanks for the response! Should that actually update df or do I need to do anything else? After running that on df and then printing df, df looks the same as before.

Comment: Dplyr commands will always return a new data frame and will not update in place. If you wish to save the result be sure to assign it to a variable. You can overwrite the original data frame if you want.

Answer (score 0):

in base R you could do:

```
df[[2]] <- do.call(Map, c(`[<-`, df[c(2,1,3)]))
```

or

```
df[[2]] <-  Map(`[[<-`, df$material_balance, df$tile_type_index,df$material_spend)
```